# base.OnCreate(bundle); Unhandled Exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm just starting to learn Xamarin Forms and when trying to run my first blank app (PCI), it throws exception:

[image: Exception image]

No matter if I deploy it on virtual Android device or directly on my phone. Also, I am using Visual Studio 2017 RC, since I could not install update 3 bugfix (KB3165756) on machine at my workplace, which is crucial(as I got it from MSDN forum post) for running cross-platform apps on VS 2015. 
There is "Master Detail" template for cross-platform projects in VS2017RC, which provides some simple App template and it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception description says is it all.

Check your style in the Resources\values\styles.xml.
There is probably a parent like this:

`parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

Which you have to change to something like this:

`parent="Theme.AppCompat"`

Or change the inheritance of the `MainActivity` to `FormsApplicationActivity`.

Also check the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/) on implementing AppCompat. If this is a blank project it is probably a bug in the project template.

Comment: My [styles.css][1] already have parent App.Compat. I did change parent ="MainTheme.Base" to parent="Theme.AppCombat", it still threw the exception. Also my [MainActivity][2] already inherits FormsApplicationActivity.


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e04fs.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqQwm.jpg

Comment: In the screenshot your `MainActivity` inherits from `FormsAppCompatActivity` not `FormsApplicationActivity`. Nevertheless your theme seems to have the right parent so it's weird that doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can publish your sample solution for us to try to reproduce